# Local filesystem access in browser extensions

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I'm doing some investigation into options for an app I am building. Do browser extensions for all browser platforms have filesystem access like Firefox does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions do not allow arbitrary filesystem access. You could, however, write an [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) plugin, but this comes with some heavy caveats:

You can also use HTML5 [filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/)s to access a sandboxed filesystem:

Answer (score 0):

Dolphin browser looks to have it. [Look at their API](http://dev.dolphin-browser.com/web-app-guide/local-file-access/) (I didn't test it yet).
Hopefully it will help you.