# Converting multiple file extensions in a directory using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, type-conversion

I am a asp.net developer. Users can upload their pictures in my application and view them later. When a user views his own pictures selects filter category as extensions, i want to filter them by extensions. I want to use javascript to filter .jpg, .png in a application folder..if user wants to view based on extensions. Is that possible ?

Comment: Its impossible. (in client and with javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read files on a server using ASP.Net. With a little effort (and file system permissions) you can create a simple file browser in a web page, and rename files using the `System.IO` namespace. Again, this will read and modify files **on the server**.

JavaScript has extremely limited access to a user's machine (for good reason). It is not possible to modify files on a user's machine using JavaScript from a typical web page (it might be possible in some cases with [browser extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641459/local-filesystem-access-in-browser-extensions)).

If you want to allow users of your ASP.Net website to modify files on **their** machine (i.e. the client), then you have a few choices:

- Create an application that they can download and run on their own machine.
- Use a browser plugin ([Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811736/can-flash-action-script-read-and-write-local-file-system), [Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276923/how-to-access-the-local-file-system-in-silverlight), ActiveX, Java). These all come with *many* caveats and they are poor choices in my opinion, but they can technically give you access to the file system.

Comment: Thanks Tim :-) i have no reputation to vote up :-(

Comment: @codebrain You can accept it as answer, and after some days that you get reputation to come and give +1.