# Copy files from user system

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an extension which copys from a folder from a path to another path using javascript in a google chrome extension (else I can't access the user system I think)

I've already found this out that I have to add "file://*" in the manifest in order to access those files and of course there is the File API in HTML5.

But how can I copy the files? From html5rocks I know how to read them, but I couldn't find out how to copy them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot access an arbitrary location on the user's filesystem (for writing).

Both, the related HTML5 APIs and the `chrome.fileSystem` API do not allow to modify or save files to arbitrary location on the user's filesystem. Your app/extension will be allowed to operate within a confined, **sandboxed** environment (virtual filesystem).

There are a few related answers here, in StackOverflow, e.g.:
**[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641459/local-filesystem-access-in-browser-extensions)**, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218890/chrome-extension-html-filesystem-access)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429513/writing-to-local-file-system-in-chrome-extension)**

More info on the APIs:

- **[File API Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)**
- **[Introduction to the FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System/Introduction)**
- **[chrome.fileSystem API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html)**